# Maze drawing with canvas

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, maze

As a side project I've created a maze generator using a graph. The logic for the generation works fine but I'm encountering some issues with rendering it. In my logic every cell is represented as an array of 4 edges where the first edge is the top wall, the second one is the right wall and so on in a clockwise direction. If there is an edge(anything different from -1) there should be a wall, if there is -1  that side should be open.

For attempting to follow this logic I've created the following Render class

```
export class Renderer {
  private _context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private _y: number;
  private _x: number;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, xSize: number, ySize: number) {
    this._context = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    this._x = xSize;
    this._y = ySize
  }


  public render(graphAdjacencyList: Array<Vertex>): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this._x; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this._y; j++) {
        const codedIndex: number = parseInt(i.toString() + j.toString());
        this._renderCell({ x: 20 * j, y: 20 * i }, graphAdjacencyList[codedIndex].getEdges(), 20)
      }
    }
  }


  private _renderCell(coords: Record<'x' | 'y', number>, cellWalls: Array<number>, size: number) {
    cellWalls.forEach((w: number, index: number) => {
      this._context.beginPath();
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          this._context.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
          (w !== -1) ? this._context.lineTo(coords.x + size, coords.y) : null;
          break;
        case 1:
          this._context.moveTo(coords.x + size, coords.y);
          (w !== -1) ? this._context.lineTo(coords.x + size, coords.y + size) : null;
          break;
        case 2:
          this._context.moveTo(coords.x + size, coords.y + size);
          (w !== -1) ? this._context.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y + size) : null;
          break;
        case 3:
          this._context.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y + size);
          (w !== -1) ? this._context.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y - size) : this._context.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y - size);
          break;
      }

      this._context.closePath();
      this._context.stroke();
    });
  }
}
```

which on a first glance seem's to work fine, except for the fact that it renders "ghost walls"(ligh grey strokes) like in this image [image: 5X5 maze]

If i glance at the edges i can see that for example the cell `[3][3]` is supposed to have only the top and left wall because it's edges are `[23, -1, -1, 32]`. I'm convinced that the error is in how i move the point's but I cannot quite pin down the issue.

minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ys9a1j

in the minimal example the graph is not randomized, but is designed in a way that the result should consist into all blocks to have only the bottom and left wall ([-1,-1, 1, 1])

Comment: Very hard to help you for me (not used to read code so verbose, nor TypeScript in general), + input is missing, but for a start, you probably don't need `this._context.closePath();` even though it should not have visible effects here. Could you set up an [MCVE] where everything that is not required to reproduce the issue simply is not there?

Comment: Also the difference of color would indicate that you draw twice at the same positions. Try to offset all your coords by 0.5 so your stroke takes a full pixel instead of bleeding over two.

Comment: @Kaiido I've added the bare minimum example, and I can see that the rendering is incorrect.. I'm sorry for the quality of code, but is more a personal POC at this stage.

Comment: Could it be that your maze logic makes it so that two cells with a wall in between them, each draw their shared wall once (so it is painted twice in total)? If that's the case, your painting function should be ok, the problem would be the logic for creating your maze (putting walls on one cell where there shouldn't be any)

Comment: Yes @Sven that's the problem ;-) I'm composing an answer at the moment, but if you feel you have a good data structure, I'd be interested in reading about it, I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: @Kaiido No, not a maze expert haha. Just hopping on the thought train. I feel like, looking at your answer, that's all there is to be said for now (without the logic function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, reviewing the code with a friend we noticed that the case 3 of the render cell was drawing the wrong line. This is how the code has been fixed.

Thanks to Kaiido, I resolved even the issue with the lighter grey strokes with his advice to offset by 0.5 the coordinates.

```
  case 3:
          this._adjustedMoveTo(coords.x, coords.y + size);
          (w !== -1) ? this._adjustedLineTo(coords.x, coords.y) : null
          break;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic problem here: you are defining the four edges of every cells independently.

If for instance we have the cell B2 being -1,-1,-1,-1 (all open) and C2 being 1,1,1,1 (all closed), the edge between these two cells will be closed by C2 declaration, even though B2 declarations says it should be open.

```
 _A_|_B_|_C_|_D_|
|        
1        
|    ooo|‾‾‾|
2    o o|   |                – -> closed (wall)
|    ooo|___|                o -> open (no wall)
```

To avoid that, you need to rethink your logic so that you either check if said wall wasn't declared before, or even better, so that you store it only once.

Two ways I can think of, though untested:

<s>- Generate a graph. From the entrance of your maze, you generate a node, which will have four properties: N,S,W,E each pointing to an other node if open, or to `null` if there should be a wall.</s>    *After testing, I found that the graph idea actually needs to also have a lookup method, or it can only go in two directions...*

- 2 2D arrays, one only for the walls on the columns, one only for the ones on the rows.

```js
const cellWidth = 20;
const maze = generateMaze(12, 12);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(cellWidth + 0.5, cellWidth + 0.5);
ctx.beginPath();
drawCols(maze.cols);
drawRows(maze.rows);
ctx.stroke();

function generateMaze(width, height) {
  const rows = generateCells(width, height);
  const cols = generateCells(height, width);
  return { cols, rows};

  function generateCells(a, b) {
    return Array.from({ length: a })
      .map(_ => Array.from({ length: b })
        .map(_ => Math.random() < 0.5)
      );
  }

}

function drawCols(list) {
  list.forEach((arr, x) => {
    arr.forEach((bool, y) => {
      if (bool) {
        ctx.moveTo(x * cellWidth, y * cellWidth);
        ctx.lineTo(x * cellWidth, y * cellWidth + cellWidth);
      }
    });
  });
}

function drawRows(list) {
  list.forEach((arr, y) => {
    arr.forEach((bool, x) => {
      if (bool) {
        ctx.moveTo(x * cellWidth, y * cellWidth);
        ctx.lineTo(x * cellWidth + cellWidth, y * cellWidth);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet which is really interesting to see another approch, I see what you mean, but that lack of logic is only happening into the simplified example. I generate the maze as an un-directed graph. when I'm declaring an open wall ( setting an edge as -1) the relationship is removed from both nodes, tho i got the problem. Was case 3 that was rendering a wrong line